# Какое слово пишется с большой буквы

Tags: языкознание

питерские крыши.
мост лейтенанта шмидта.
суворовская тактика.

Comment: @zaxar z, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> Какое слово пишется с большой буквы?

Здесь два таких слова:

***мост Лейтенанта Шмидта***

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=84#pp84 :

> **§ 169.** В географических и административно-территориальных
> названиях — названиях материков,
> морей, озер, рек, возвышенностей, гор,
> стран, краев, областей, населенных
> пунктов, улиц и т. п. — с прописной
> буквы пишутся все слова, кроме родовых
> понятий *(остров, море, гора, область,
> провинция, улица, площадь и т. п.)*,
> служебных слов, а также слов *года,
> лет…*